# jQuery methods not working inside Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel with various boxes rotating.

When I click on a button within the box, I want to toggle a class to a div within the same box.

It works fine when until i wrap it in an owl carousel and initialise it. After that the toggleClass method (and any other method seemingly) seems to stop working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.view-offer').click(function() {

    var linkID = $(this).data('id')
    var el = '#box-' + linkID
    $(el).toggleClass('test');

    console.log(el);

  });

  $(".offers-slider").owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
      "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
    ],
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    items: 3
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme offers-slider">

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#!" class="view-offer" data-id="1">View</a>
    <div id="box-1">
      Box 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#!" class="view-offer" data-id="2">View</a>
    <div id="box-2">
      Box 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#!" class="view-offer" data-id="3">View</a>
    <div id="box-3">
      Box 3
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

linkID will log to the console fine but the class will not add to element. There are no errors at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element in the Carousel has the same list of the box that means if you have tree boxes each item in the Carousel while containing `#box-1` and `#box-2` and `#box-3`. So you need to get the closest box to your link:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.view-offer').click(function() {

    var linkID = $(this).data('id')
    var el = '#box-' + linkID
    $(this).siblings(el).toggleClass('test');

    console.log(el);

  });

  $(".offers-slider").owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
      "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
    ],
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    items: 3
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme offers-slider">

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#!" class="view-offer" data-id="1">View</a>
    <div id="box-1">
      Box 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#!" class="view-offer" data-id="2">View</a>
    <div id="box-2">
      Box 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#!" class="view-offer" data-id="3">View</a>
    <div id="box-3">
      Box 3
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: their is three div with the same id "#box-1" in the DOM

Comment: You're right, so the html is invalid and @cnrhgn should not use duplicate id

Comment: I didn't use the same ID for any element. Owl Carousel duplicates the slides upon initialisation. But this solved the problem. Thanks